# Shopify: Adding a Custom Content Block to Collection Pages inside the Product Grid

Tags: pagination, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I'm attempting to create a custom content block that can be placed anywhere in the product grid in collection pages.

I can get a custom content block to render inside the product grid on collection pages, and I've linked up a range slider in the block's schema to choose the grid position number. That was easy enough.

I'm running into a problem with pagination. Say there's 9 products per page (3 products per row, 3 rows total) and 12 products in the store. Without the custom content block, 9 products display per page, but turning the custom content block on will add a tenth block to the first page.

**Problem #1: How to update the product grid so that when a custom content block is added into the grid, the 9th product flows on to the second page? And so on for each subsequent page in the pagination?**

The range slider for the custom content block has a max of 9, because if it goes above that number then the custom content block disappears, the reason being, pagination breaks the products into 9 products per page. Page/2 in the pagination has only 9 products, and so on for each page.

**Problem #2: How to get the custom content block to appear on the 2nd or 3rd (and so on) pages in the pagination?**

A simplified version of my collection-template.liquid file:

```
{%- liquid
  assign per_row = 3
  assign paginate_by = per_row | times: 3

  for block in section.blocks
    case block.type
    when 'product_grid'
      assign per_row = block.settings.per_row
      assign paginate_by = per_row | times: block.settings.rows_per_page
    endcase
  endfor
-%}

{%- paginate collection.products by paginate_by -%}

  {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
    <div {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
      {%- case block.type -%}
      {%- when 'product_grid' -%}

        {% assign product_counter = 0 %}

        {%- for product in collection.products -%}

          {%- assign product_counter = product_counter | plus: 1 -%}

          {% if product_counter == grid_placement %}
            {%- render 'product-grid-promo', grid_item_width: grid_item_width, per_row: per_row -%}
           {%- endif -%} 

           {%- render 'product-grid-item', product: product, grid_item_width: grid_item_width, per_row: per_row -%}

          {%- endfor -%}
      </div>
      {%- if paginate.pages > 1 -%}
        {%- render 'pagination', paginate: paginate -%}
      {%- endif -%}

    {%- endcase -%}
  </div>
{%- endfor -%}

{%- endpaginate -%}
```

I want this to be flexible enough, that my client (the merchant) could add several custom content blocks into the product grid, and the grid would adjust accordingly. I also want the ability to add custom content blocks to each page in the pagination.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this, so I'm answering my own question. Hopefully this helps someone else.

First we count the number of content blocks (promo blocks) in the loop:

```
{%- liquid

    assign promo_block_counter = 0

    for block in section.blocks
        case block.type
        when 'product_grid_promo'

            assign promo_block_counter = promo_block_counter | plus: 1

        when 'product_grid'  
            assign per_row = block.settings.per_row
            assign paginate_by = per_row | times: block.settings.rows_per_page
        endcase
    endfor

-%}
```

Then we assign `paginate_by` to a variable, and run the variable through a switch statement where the case is the number of promo blocks in the loop. If the number of promo blocks is 1, we subtract 1 from `paginate_by`, and so on up to 3 (in this instance I didn't want the merchant to be able to add more than 3 promo blocks into the grid):

```
{%- liquid

    assign number_of_grid_items = paginate_by

    case promo_block_counter
        when 1
        assign number_of_grid_items = paginate_by | minus: 1
        when 2
        assign number_of_grid_items = paginate_by | minus: 2
        when 3
        assign number_of_grid_items = paginate_by | minus: 3
    endcase

-%}
```

We update the paginate wrapper with the now correct number of items in the grid, which will adjust according to how many promo blocks have been added:

```
{%- paginate collection.products by number_of_grid_items -%}
```

A few notes about the code below. I used to have the promo block code in its own snippet liquid file, but it appears that when you have a block nested inside a block, as is the case below (promo block nested inside product grid block), I wasn't able to figure out a method for counting the promo blocks. The only way I could get it to work, was to bring the snippet code directly into the collection template file. One thing I am not totally sure of, is the forloop inside the forloop causing any performance issues? Is there a better way to structure this?

```
{%- paginate collection.products by number_of_grid_items -%}

    {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
        <div {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
            {%- case block.type -%}
            {%- when 'product_grid' -%}
                
              {%- assign product_counter = 0 -%}

              {%- for product in collection.products -%}

                {%- assign product_counter = product_counter | plus: 1 -%}
                        
                    {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
                      {%- case block.type -%}
                      {%- when 'product_grid_promo' -%}

                        {%- if product_counter == block.settings.grid_placement -%}
                                
                            <div class="grid__item grid-product {{ grid_item_width }}" data-block-id="{{ block.id }}" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>

                                         {%- comment -%} promo block content goes here {%- endcomment -%}
                                    </div>
                                {%- endif -%}
                            {%- endcase -%}
                        {%- endfor -%}
                
                        {%- render 'product-grid-item', product: product, grid_item_width: grid_item_width, per_row: per_row -%}

                    {%- else -%}
                        <div class="grid__item">
                            <p>{{ 'collections.general.no_matches' | t }}</p>
                        </div>
                    {%- endfor -%}
                </div>

                {%- if paginate.pages > 1 -%}
                    {%- render 'pagination', paginate: paginate -%}
                {%- endif -%}
    
            {%- endcase -%}
        </div>
    {%- endfor -%}

{%- endpaginate -%}
```